# How to execute two commands in RUN command in docker?

Tags: linux, apache, docker, service, cups

I am creating a **Docker** image based on **httpd**.

I am installing **CUPS software** in that and trying to add a printer in that.

After installing CUPS in the docker image using **RUN** command - `RUN ["apt", "install", "-y", "cups"]`, in the next step I'm trying to **restart cups service** and then **add a printer** using lpadmin command.

`service cups start`

`lpadmin -p printer_name -E -v url -m everywhere`

But it is only working when I put both those service start and add printer commands in single RUN command by using && symbol between them as follows:

`RUN ["service cups start", "&&", "lpadmin -p printer_name -E -v url -m everywhere"]`

If I put them separately as follows:

`RUN ["service cups start"]`

`RUN ["lpadmin -p printer_name -E -v url -m everywhere"]`

it is giving me the below error:

`lpadmin: Unable to connect to server: Bad file descriptor`

Here's my part of Dockerfile content:

```
USER root

RUN ["apt", "update"]

RUN ["apt", "install", "-y", "cups"]

RUN ["systemctl", "enable", "cups"]

RUN ["service", "cups", "start", "&&", "./printerslist.sh"]

RUN ["chmod", "-R", "-f", "777", "/var/run"]

ENTRYPOINT ["service", "cups", "restart"]
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming and should be over at https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux# or https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/linux

Comment: You can't start background processes in Dockerfiles.  As a general rule commands like `service` don't work in Docker at all.  If you need a print daemon running somewhere, running it in a separate container (or better still on the host, if the printer is physically connected) is probably a better model.

Comment: That issue was resolved. But I got new issue. The docker container is stuck at ENTRYPOINT which is `service cups start`. I'm trying to deploy the container in OCP. and the container log is stuck at `Starting Common Unix Printing System: cupsd`. Any idea how to resolve this?